# Swift Cannot Insert int value inside a tuple array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, int, tuples

I am trying to store an int value inside a tuple array.
The array has this format:

```
var array: [(object1:Object1,object2:Object2,number:Int)]
```

I have a tableview, with buttons and textfields inside it's cells.
In a button, with an action sheet string picker i give values to the textFields.

```
 func buttonPressed(){
let cell = button.superview?.superview? as? CustomCellClass

//i use a string picker to fill the JVFLoatLabeledTextField
// then i acces link the arrays, index to the current cell


let currentIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

 array[currentIndex.row].number = Int(cell.textfield.text!)!

 //i also insert the objects in the array, but they work fine

}
```

but when i try to acces all the stored data from different cells
like this:

```
    for tuple in array {

print(tuple.object1.name)
print(tuple.object2.name)
print(tuple.number)

}
```

the output will be: object1.name, object2.name, 0 .... every tuple.number has the value 0.

If anyone gives any suggestion I'd appreciated it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow down the problem I would try:

`array[currentIndex.row].number = currentIndex.row`

If you get the expected result when you iterate through the array that will demonstrate that the issue is not with the tuple array. Check value returned from the expression

`Int(cell.textfield.text!)!`